# GNOME problem in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.04

I installed GNOME 3.8 in Ubuntu 13.04, and the UI in Unity also changed. And I kept getting messages that there was an error in my system and the error has to be reported. This actually started after installing Gnome. And when I was browsing, I faced problems with loading of images in Facebook, etc.

This all happened only after installing GNOME. And when I tried uninstalling it using 
`apt-get purge gnome-shell-*` , GNOME desktop environment got removed, but the problem of image loading still exists and the skin of Unity is not as it was before.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I didn't get this: How do you relate the problem of image loading in a browser to the shell installed?

Comment: i was browsing in facebook jus before installing gnome. And immediately after restarting, i logged in to find that images were not loading...

Comment: When you say, that you reinstalled your system, did you also format the harddisk?

Comment: @user125253: No I did not format my hardddisk. Just  new copy of ubnutu-gnome

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalled my system with `ubuntu-gnome` and the problem is over. I don't get system errors and image problems anymore. What i suggest all is not to install more than one desktop environment in your system..

Answer (score 0):

This happens often when you install any Desktop Environment next to another.
I would recommend re installing Ubuntu, whether it will be normal Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Gnome.

What you could also do is (on a secondary machine or Virtual Machine)
enter

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

and see which packages it would install and remove all of those.
It may break your system even more or it maybe helps, never tried that.

I also would recommend to never update Gnome or Unity or anything else (Just speaking from experience)

Comment: didnt work.. :(

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The problem persists. immediately after i login to the system, i get an error message: `System error detected`. And the image problem

Comment: is there any way unity can be removed and this problem solved?

Comment: I guess you have to reinstall the System. I am not certain if the Problem is fixable, and even if it is whether it's worth the hassle.

Comment: so do you mean i cannot install gnome at all?

Comment: If you want Gnome I recommend you Ubuntu Gnome http://ubuntugnome.org/download/ , as in mine and in your experience installing Desktop Environments ends up badly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are telling is not effected by the 'Gnome' installation.
Make sure about your network connection.

About the system error, there are several reason because of the unstable version of the ubuntu 13.04.

About system unity use the different desktop environment if the problem persist.
logout the System--- at ***gnome Login Screen*** choose different **Session** below of you **password** field.

do check you problem by using **System Testing** application in unity. it may helps.